# Nginx+Apache環境でのPHP7.3-fpmの動作について

Tags: php, apache, nginx

お世話になっております。
Apacheをインストールして、Nginxをリバースプロキシとして利用しています。
この環境にPHP7.3-fpmを組み込んだのですが、存在しないPHPファイルにアクセスすると、下記のエラーが表示されます。

```
No input file specified.
```

これをApacheの404エラーページが表示されるようにするには、どうしたらよいでしょうか。
ちなみに、Nginxの設定ファイルを一部抜粋して掲載します。

```
server {
  root /home/example/public_html/example.com;
  server_name example.com;
  client_max_body_size 20M;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

環境は、Ubuntu 18.04、Apache 2.4.29、Nginx 1.16.1です。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

パスが **.php** のときに、`if` 文を使って、ファイルが存在しなければ別の処理をするようにします。
Nginx で 404 を返す例です。

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Apache で 404 を返すのであれば、`return 404` の替わりに `proxy_pass` を使うとできそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「Apache で 404 を返すのであれば、return 404 の替わりに proxy_pass を使うとできそうです。」というのは、どのように指定するのでしょうか。ざっと調べてみたのですが、よくわかりませんでした。というか、本当はPHPをApacheで実行させるようにすればいいのでしょうが、PHP7.3のApache用fastcgiのインストール方法がよくわからず、結局Nginxで動かしている次第です。

Comment: 「location / { }」内の設定を「return 404」の替わりに設定すれば、.php ファイルがない場合、127.0.0.1:8080 (Apache) にプロキシして、結果、Apache の 404 が返ると思います。
わざわざそうする必要があるのかは疑問ですが。

Comment: こんにちは、返信遅くなってすみません。結局「return 404」で設定しました。ありがとうございました。